# Xcode 14 xcode archive error unsupported Swift architecture import swiftModule

Tags: xcode

when I try to archive a framework for the arm64 architecture, I'm getting this error

this happens when i build new version of framework with the xcode14.

```
fatal error: 
      could not build module 'MAdvertiseLocation'
@import MAdvertiseLocation;


 error: 
      unsupported Swift architecture
#error unsupported Swift architecture
 ^
1 error generated.
```

Any idea please

Comment: I have same issue which happens only while building for simulator, please let me know if you found any solution.

Comment: Any solution for this issue? I have same issue with my own created Library and using 14.2